# Obtain function from compositions of itself

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I was attempting a question and wondered how I could go about obtaining an original function from the definition of several of its compositions.

i.e.

Consider $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$(g \circ g \circ g)(a) - a = (g \circ g)(a)\,\,\,\,\,$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$

How can I obtain $g(a)$?

I tried setting $(g \circ g)(a) = h$ and substituting it in to get $g(h) = h + a$ but I want its definition to pass $a$ as the input, not specifically $(g \circ g)(a)$.

Hints but not full answers would be appreciated!

Comment: So, you're trying to solve the functional equation $(g \circ g \circ g)(a) - a = (g \circ g)(a)$ for the function $g$? What is the domain/codomain of $g$? $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @user854214 ah, I've edited the question to include the domain/codomain. And yes, I'm trying to solve it to obtain $g(a)$ so that I can begin to prove whether $g(a)$ is injective.

Comment: Well, in thinking about this problem, the only things I can show about $g$ is that it is injective, and $g(0) = 0$ is the only fixed point. If you just need to prove injectivity, I wouldn't recommend trying to solve for $g$.

Comment: I see. Why would you not recommend that? How else would I go about trying to prove its injectivity?

Comment: Just start by assuming $g(a) = g(b)$. By applying $g$ to both sides one or two more times, and using the functional equation, you can conclude that $a = b$. I would give you a full answer, but you prefer hints. Solving for $g$ seems hard to me. I don't know for sure, but I suspect that there are some horrible unconstructable discontinuous solutions for $g$. What I do know is that these solutions will inevitably be injective.

Comment: So I assume $g(a) = g(b)$ and apply $g$ once to both sides to get $(g \circ g)(a) = (g \circ g) (b)$. Using the equation, I can then rewrite it as $(g \circ g \circ g)(a) - a = (g \circ g \circ g)(b) - b$. We know the first two parts are equal, so I end up with $-a = -b \rightarrow a = b \therefore$ the function is injective. Does this seem fine? If it's incorrect, then a full answer may be better for me!

Comment: That's right! It's an easier argument than figuring out all the possible functions $g$.

Comment: Fantastic. That's a lot easier than I thought. Thank you! You also mentioned that you can show that $g(0) = 0$. How would you do that?

Comment: Well, I noticed that when $a = 0$, we see that $k = (g \circ g)(0)$ is a fixed point of $g$, i.e. $g(k) = k$. But then, applying $g$ more times, $k = (g \circ g)(k) = (g \circ g \circ g)(k)$, and so $k = (g \circ g \circ g)(k) - (g \circ g)(k) = 0$ using the functional equation. That is, $0$ is the one and only fixed point of $g$ (and happens to be the same as $(g \circ g)(0)$).